# Give Error page click Anchor tag -Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to give Error Message ,clicking any Anchor tag at the time of Page Loading.

For E.g: If i am clicking onlink, now page is loading, in this time user clicking any other anchor tag in page report some alert message

Comment: what is error and where is code.?

Comment: `clicking any Anchor tag at the time of Page Loading` plz explain a bit more.

Comment: Simply OP is asking if user clicks on anchor tag while page is still loading then he should get some error message

Comment: check using ajax function/ jquery $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

check using ajax function/ jquery

```
if ($(document).ready())
 //do process on click
else
  alert ("not ready"); //Error message
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
$(function () {
   var count = 0;
   if (count == 0) {
      $('button').click(function () {
        alert('Error');
      });

      $(window).load(function () {
        count++;
        if (count != 0) {
            $('button').click(function () {
                alert('Good.');
            });
        }
      });
   }
});
```

On `doc ready` use a `var count` which holds a value of `0` `at the time of loading` it will force the button to `alert('Error')` and when window completely get loaded then `alert(Good);`.